# Sort a table of 12 php variables and limit the rows to lowest 5 on page load

Tags: php, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I asked this question the other day but I deleted it because I was way too vague so here it is with more detail hopefully someone can help.  Sorry if the explanation is long but I want to make sure it makes sense this time.

I have a fitness website that shows people scores of their fitness tests running on drupal so I am using mysql and php.

The site also has a feature called `Trianables`. Trainables are things that you can work on, like speed and power, that will help you get better at your sport.  There are a total of 12 trainables.

You have a score for every trainable which are calculated by php code that selects 1 or more fitness test result from the database (depending on the trainable), calculates where you rank compared to other athletes in the database, puts that calculation into a number from 1-5 with 1 being the lowest 20% of athletes and 5 being the top 20% of athletes and then stores this number in a php variable so I can place it on different areas of the page. I usually do this with an image using code like this

```
echo "<img src='http://example.com/images/score$Balance.png'>";
```

This example would give me an image called score4.png.  I have score1.png-score5.png

**I show the trainable scores on different tabs within the page but what I want to do is show on the first tab the 5 trainables in which they have the lowest scores (like 1s and 2s) and an exercise for each one so they can see the 5 most important exercises to improve.**

This will require a script that takes all 12 variables (1 for each trainable), ranks them from lowest number to highest, and then outputs only the lowest 5.

Is the best way to do this with an array? I have figured out how to use an array to spit out the lowest 5 numbers in order using this code

```
<?php

$worsttrains=array($trainable1, $trainable2, $trainable3, $trainable4, $trainable5, $trainable6, $trainable7, $trainable8, $trainable9, $trainable10, $trainable11, $trainable12);

asort($worsttrains, SORT_NUMERIC);
$worst5trains=array_slice($worsttrains, 0, 5, true);

foreach ($worst5trains as $a)

echo " ".$a ;

echo "<br>";


?>
```

In the end I guess I want the data displayed in a table format like the code below but I need a code that has it sorted by the variable in the score column, it needs to carry the other information with it in its row (the trainable and the exercise) and only the 5 rows with the lowest variables can be displayed. Is this possible with an array or do I need to look at something like jquery?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Trainable</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  <th>Exercise</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Balance</td>
 <td>$balance</td>
 <td>Balance Board Squat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Lower Strength</td>
 <td>$lowerstrength</td>
 <td>Squats</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Lower Power</td>
 <td>$lowerpower</td>
 <td>Forward Jump Squats</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Lower Quickness</td>
 <td>$lowerquickness</td>
 <td>Skater Hop</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Reaction Time</td>
 <td>$reactiontime</td>
 <td>4 Corner Listen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Brakes</td>
 <td>$brakes</td>
 <td>Monger Hop</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Upper Quickness</td>
 <td>$upperquickness</td>
 <td>Light Ball Toss</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I could also use div's if that is easier than doing it in a table.

I hope this makes sense if you need clarification just ask.

Comment: Why can't you simply put the code that generates the HTML table in your `foreach` array? It seems you've already figured out how to get the five values you're interested in.

Comment: That seemed like it would be the simpelest solution to me but I think I've just spent too much time staring at this code too long. How would I make it so that each row carrys its other values with it.

Meaning 
row 1 would be Balance, $variable, balance exercise
row 2 would be Reaction, $variable, reaction exercise

so no matter what order it puts the variables in they carry those other two columns with it.

Maybe I don't make sense because I am over thinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
   array(0 => "trainable",1=>100,2=>"exercise"),
   array(0 => "balance",1=>50,2=>"balance board squat"),
   array(0 => "lower strength",1=>200,2=>"squats")
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $score[$key]  = $row[1];
}

array_multisort($score, SORT_ASC, $arr);

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => balance
            [1] => 50
            [2] => balance board squat
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => trainable
            [1] => 100
            [2] => exercise
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lower strength
            [1] => 200
            [2] => exercise
        )

)
```

which you can splice as needed, and then you can print the table. Of course, you can expand the initial array (`$arr`) to contain 12 exercises, or more if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond I really appreciate it. I actually came up with basically this exact answer yesterday after hours of digging through the php website and looking at different code. This confirms that my code is right though and not just a big hack job so thank you for that! I have marked this as the answer incase it helps anyone else out there.